# How do I tell python to ignore a certain specified bone when it is not present in the armature

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a script to certain bones inside of an armature.
But if the script cannot find one of the bones I have specified the whole script just dies out and doesn't run any further. how can I make it so that if the script can't find a bone it ignores that bone and goes onto the next line of code.

Comment: Check if the bone exist and run the next line: `if bone: print("Do something")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` statement in Python script.
See the [document here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

A simple script:

```
a_list = [1,0,2,3,4,5]
result_list = []
while a_list:
    try: # Try to run this block
        divider = a_list[-1]
        result = 60 / divider
        result_list.append(result)
    except: # if "any" Error happen, do this block
        print(f"Oops, something go wrong: divider:{divider}")
        break
    finally: # whether there is an error or what, run this block
        a_list.pop()
result_list
```

Output:

```
Oops, something go wrong: divider:0
[12.0, 15.0, 20.0, 30.0]
```

> Please don't silently bypass an error in code, let user know what happens and if possible, let them decide what to do explicit.